# How indexes will perform in such scenarios?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

i read a lot about indexes in sql and got it almost clear but still confusion. Like if i put clustered index on primary key ID (which is by default) so how will this queries perform in that case

```
1. Select * from tableInfo where ID > 1200
```

and

```
2. Select * from tableInfo where ID = 12000
```

Note: table has rows from 1 - 15000.

would it first check the ID in index list and then if it finds it in list then it will return record ? right ?

Update:
does it work like that: in case of #2 it will first look for 12000 in list if found then will return data being selected. but how it will perform in case of #1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the query plan
Both should be a clustered index seek

Comment: right but does it work like that: in case of #2 it will first look for 12000 in list if found then will return data being selected.


but how it will perform in case of #1 ?

Comment: What part of "both should be a clustered index seek" is not clear?  Did you examine the query plan?